# Progress bar has a border by default in the Edge browser

Tags: css, html, microsoft-edge

I have an issue with my progress bar in Edge (version 25.10586.672.0). By default, the progress bar I've implemented has a border on it. There is no border by default in neither Chrome nor Firefox. I can remove it no problem by setting the CSS property border to none, however there is still a divider line as the bar is being filled (i.e. if the bar is filled halfway, there is a little line between the filled in section and the unfilled section) that does not go away even with setting border to none.

I was curious if there was a particular CSS property I need to modify for this, or perhaps there's another underlying reason why there is a border being set in  edge for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge use some special CSS selectors. [In this codepen](https://codepen.io/bjankord/pen/JKRxqX) you can see a working example.

The important CSS Selector is:

```
progress.with-border-fix::-ms-fill {
  border-color: currentColor;
}
```